# Ninject Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject

I have a wcf service application and I have just implemented ninject library. In ninject web site there is following example:

```
public class Samurai {
    public IWeapon Weapon { get; private set; }
    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon) 
    {
        this.Weapon = weapon;
    }
}

public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        this.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
    }
}
```

I have classes like this. But problem is how can I create instance of `Samurai` class? It's constructor have parameter (`IWeapon`), but the parameter is binded `Sword` or different class. When I want to create instance of `Samurai` class, compiler expects `IWeapon` type parameter. In my module class (like `WarriorModule`) I have already defined it's binding. How can I pass parameter (or some different way) to `Samurai` class's constuctor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to do is. There is no need to create ISamurai interface. In Warriormodule:

```
public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
        Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

To create Samurai instance:

```
var samurai = kernel.Get<Samurai>();
```

Comment: A word of warning; make sure that you are certain that you are happy with `Samurai` as an immutable class type. I have no objections to self-bound types at all, just make sure that you are always going to be happy with having a single class injected rather than one that can be swapped out when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new WarriorModule());
        var samurai = kernel.Get<ISamurai>();
    }
}

public interface ISamurai
{
}

public class Samurai : ISamurai
{
    public IWeapon Weapon { get; private set; }
    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        this.Weapon = weapon;
    }
}

public interface IWeapon
{

}

public class Sword : IWeapon
{

}

public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<ISamurai>().To<Samurai>();
        this.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
    }
}
```

Comment: My project has multiple layers and according to this example IWeapon and samurai classes exists on different layers. To add interfaces for all classes that inside this layer (Samurai class layer), requires extra work load. Can I achieve this different way?